# Proper subgroup of $S_{15}$ that strictly contains $\sigma $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

How does one prove that:

> There exists *no* cyclic proper subgroup of $S_{15}$ that strictly contains the following permutation (of order $10$)? $$\sigma = (1, 2,3, 4,5, 6, 7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,15).$$

Comment: What about $\langle \sigma \rangle$?

Comment: @PVAL I mean another one that *strictly* contains $\langle \sigma \rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\tau$ is a cycle of length $n$, then $\tau^{k}$ will be the product of $\gcd(n, k)$ cycles of length $n / \gcd(n, k)$ each.

So suppose $\sigma = \vartheta^{k}$ for some $\vartheta$.

Since $\sigma$ contains a cycle of length $10$, $\vartheta$ must contain at least a cycle of length $n$ a multiple of $10$. Since $20 > 15$, there is only one such cycle in $\vartheta$, and it has length $n = 10$.

Since  $\sigma$ contains exactly one cycle of length $10$, we have $1 = \gcd(n, k) = \gcd(10, k)$.

Therefore $\vartheta$ is a power of $\sigma$.